# Kendo knockout: re-bind column template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo-knockout library. I created a dynamic table so I can switch data sources. I did a custom binding and during the update event I destroy the grid then set new options(datasource, columns, schema, etc) and "recreate" the grid .  However I'm not able to re-bind the template I set in columns.

```
  var grid = $(element).data('kendoGrid');
  grid.thead.remove();
  grid.destroy();
```

--- New options

```
column.template = "<a data-bind=\"text: status,  css: {'errorMessage': true}, click: $root.openPopup \">${status}</a>";


                $scope.dataSource({
                    data: items,
                    columns: columns,
                    schemaModelFields: schema
                });
```

in the binder during the update

```
 function (dataSource, element, vm) {
    [...]
     var gridOptions = {
                    columns: columns,
                    dataSource: {
                        data: data,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: schemaModelFields
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    [...] 



 $(element).kendoGrid(gridOptions);
```

I would like to be able to call the openPopup method from the root VM.  It does render the template correctly but the binding is broken.

```
<a data-bind="text: status,  css: {'errorMessage': true}, click: $root.openPopup">Not Set</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer for this... using the dataBound event I clean the node and re-apply the binding

```
        var gridOptions = {
                columns: columns,
                dataSource: {
                    type: 'knockout',
                    data: data,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: schemaModelFields
                        }
                    }
                },
                useKOTemplates: true,
                dataBound: dataBound,
                preventBinding: true,                    
            };

            var grid = $(element).kendoGrid(gridOptions);

           var dataBound = function () {
            var body = this.element.find("tbody")[0];

            if (body) {
                ko.cleanNode(body);
                ko.applyBindings(ko.dataFor(body), body);
            }
        }
```

This solved my issue but the context that applies to the biding is the VM from the root and not the data source items so in $root.openPopup the parameter I get is the full VM instead the row item.